# How to programmatically send a message to a Teams BOT

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a BOT running which reponds to api/messages URL from the BOT Framework Emulator, and I can send text to it.

However what I need to do is write an application which sends text to the BOT over this URL.  That is basically does what the BOT Framework Emulator does when I enter text and send it, probably over the graph API.

I am aware of information which demonstrates sending to a chat in a channel, but I just need to send to the BOT itself.

Can anyone advise how I can do this, or is there a suitable sample which demonstrates it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, your bot is really just a web api endpoint. If you set up a tunneling service like ngrok, you can use it's built-in web viewer to see the traffic that is sent to you bot, e.g. via the emulator or even via the azure bot registration page (there is a similar emulator built into the page in Azure). Once you've seen that traffic, you can essentially just mirror it from whatever you want to call from - it's essentially a json payload.

However, considering your bot is just a web api, I'm not sure why you want to "call" your bot from another app. Why not just make another endpoint that you can use for app-to-app communication (like a normal api endpoint). You can then refactor your code so that whatever you need to do can be done either via a bot message OR via the API call.

Comment: I am writing a Web Application which will be hosted as a Teams Tab, but needs to trigger functionality in a BOT.  I am aware that I can sniff the request and duplicate it, but would prefer to use an API to guard against schema changes in the json.

Comment: ah ok, got you. So yes, the API approach would work best for you in that case.

Comment: Depending on your usecase you might need to consider the pro-active scenario: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: I guess my question is what API should I be using.  The proactive sample is about a BOT sending a proactive message using the BOT Framework API.   I am not writing a BOT here, but I do want to send a proactive message to a BOT.  The graph API lets me send to Chat/Team/Group, but I dont think it specifically lets me send to a BOT.  Which API should I use to send the BOT a message. Thanks.

Comment: 'Proactive' isn't about sending a message TO the bot, it's about the Bot *starting* the conversation (usually the bot is just *replying* to something). It's hard to advise what you need at this point because the scenario is a bit unknown - perhaps give us more info what you're trying to do/ wanting to happen

Comment: The Wep App wants to trigger the BOT to make a telephone call. The Telephony side of this is working in the BOT, I just need to trigger it.

Comment: ah ok, got you. Proactive messaging is probably not what you need then anyway. What does your code look like, to trigger the call?

Comment: It is a blank canvas at this moment.  I was hoping to use the graph API, but have been looking at setting the json schema for a request.   The BOT which I need to trigger is using chat (/api/messages) and the function it needs to carry out is passed as a text string.  I will need to pass parameters at some point, but wanted to get a basic proof of concept going first.  Any suggestions welcome.